Issue with Media Player License Key Integration in Live
Could someone please assist in resolving this issue? I'm encountering difficulties using the MediaKind player's license key provided in my MediaKind account. While it operates smoothly in my local environment, it fails to function correctly on our testing and live platforms.


const playerConfig: MKPlayerConfig = {
      key: "Xxx8525XXXXXXXXXXXXdc7a8e", //license key
      playback: {
        muted: false,
        autoplay: true,
      },
      ui: true,
      appId:"XXXXXXXXX241fbaaf12171XXXX",
      events: {
        [MKPlayerEvent.Error]: (event) => {
          console.log("Encountered player error: ", JSON.stringify(event));
        },
        [MKPlayerEvent.TimeChanged]: (event) => {
         
          console.log("Current player position: ");
        },
       
      
      }
    };
    this.player = new MKPlayer(videoContainer,  playerConfig);

Thank You,
Akhila N
Do I need to purchase a separate key?

Akhila Chowdary , are using azure media-player right?
